# Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": denied: denied

Tags: docker, github-package-registry, ghcr

While using with the GitHub action I am getting `Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": denied: denied`

I used the login command `echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u $ghcr_user -password-stdin`

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I believe the command you want should be:

```
echo "$CR_PAT" | docker login ghcr.io -u "$ghcr_user" --password-stdin
```

That adds quoting to the variables and a second dash to the long arg. It also assumes those variables are defined.

That said, I tend to use the following in GitHub Actions for doing the login:

```yaml
​    - ​name​: ​Login to GHCR 
​      ​uses​: ​docker/login-action@v1  
​      ​with​: 
​        ​registry​: ​ghcr.io 
​        ​username​: ​${{ secrets.GHCR_USERNAME }} 
​        ​password​: ​${{ secrets.GHCR_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was this

```
docker login --username MY_GITHUB_USERNAME --password-stdin
[paste value of $CR_PAT here]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try logout and then login. Or even removing the docker credentials (at `~/.docker/config.json` in Linux) and then trying to login again.

This resolved the issue for me and [many others](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/43380#discussioncomment-4601450)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to run `docker login` as `sudo`.

`sudo docker login ghcr.io -u Nevah5`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u $ghcr_user --password-stdin` use

```
docker login ghcr.io -u $ghcr_user -p $CR_PAT
```

[image]

Comment: Using -p via the CLI is insecure. Should use --password-stdin instead.